# Google chart: I cant label my each (3 column) bar

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json, google-visualization

Right  now this code retrieved data from  3 columns of database and display them as a row in column chart (`hAxis`) , that means:-

1. there will be a three bar ( called from 3 columns of database)
2. but i want to label each of bar with (criteria1, criteria 2, criteria3..)
3. clear example like table below..i just want to retrieve the percentage from database that are stored in 3 columns..  the criteria will be labeled manually..

   ```
    ________________________
   |CRITERIA   |PERCENTAGE |
   |-----------------------|
   |CRITERIA 1 | 64.1      |
   |-----------------------|
   |CRITERIA 2 | 11.1      |
   |-----------------------|
   |CRITERIA 3 | 21.1      |
   |-----------------------|
   ```

   thank u very much..

**Edited :getdata.php:**

```
    $table = array();
    $table['cols'] = array
   (
    array('label' => 'Criteria', 'type' => 'string'),
    array('label' => 'Criteria 1', 'type' => 'number'),
    array('label' => 'Criteria 2', 'type' => 'number'),
    array('label' => 'Criteria 3', 'type' => 'number')
    );

   $rows = array();
   while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql_query)) 
   {
          $temp = array();
          $temp[] = array('v' =>"");
          $temp[] = array('v' => (float)$r['resultsd']);
          $temp[] = array('v' => (float)$r['resultwe']); 
          $temp[] = array('v' => (float)$r['resulttre']); 

          $rows[] = array('c' => $temp);

   }

    $table['rows'] = $rows;
    $jsonTable = json_encode($table);
    echo $jsonTable;
```

**This is google visualization code that called getdata.php.:**

```
  google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});

  function drawVisualization()
   {
    var jsonData=null;
    var json = $.ajax
    ({

      url:"getdata.php?id=<?php echo $_GET['id'];?>", 
      dataType: "json",
      async: false,

      success: (
      function(data) 
      {
         jsonData = data;  

         var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonData);            

         var options = 
         {
            title: 'SAM Histogram Results',
            hAxis: {title: " CRITERIA TYPE", titleTextStyle: {italic: false,bold: true}},  
            vAxis: {title: "PERCENTAGE (%)", titleTextStyle: {italic: false, bold: true}},
            titleTextStyle: {color: 'black', bold:'true'},  
        }
    var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('visualization')).
    draw(data,options);  

    })
    }).responseText;
  }
  google.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization);
```

Comment: somebody please help, i have post this question twice..

Comment: its ok..never mind..i made it by myself..thank u very much.. :)